# Erro ao fazer clone com Git

Tags: git, github, versionamento

Quando tento fazer um clone de um repositório através do Git Bash por linha de comando me retorna este erro, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou numa rede corporativa, pode ser o firewall me bloqueando?
Alguém já passou por algo do tipo?

Comment: esse link funcionou para mim... teste `$ git clone http://github.com/Luitame/museu_virtual.git`

Comment: Agora também funcionou para mim dessa forma via `HTTP`. Mas, por que não funcionou por `SSH` ? Deve ter algum erro de configuração dela ou o firewall da empresa ta bloqueando. Concorda @Sergio ?

Comment: O link que o Sergio passou é de read-only, por isso funciona, para copiar via ssh você precisa gerar as chaves publica e privada. [Aqui](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows), tem um tutorial que pode te ajudar

Comment: @Luitame eu acho que é o firewall que está a causar problemas aqui.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tive o mesmo problema e achei a seguinte solução.

Mensagem de erro:

```
ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_5.8p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0d 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 207.97.227.239 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
```

Você verá uma mensagem de bad file number quando estiver no Windows usando MINGGW shell e para usuários linux Timed out.

Problema:

O SSH está blockeado na porta 22, digite:

> $nmap -sS github.com -p 22

pra ver o seguinte:

```
$nmap -sS github.com -p 22
Starting Nmap 5.35DC1 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-11-05 10:53 CET
Nmap scan report for github.com (207.97.227.239)
Host is up (0.10s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp ***filtered*** ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 2.63 seconds
```

Como pode ver o state está como Filtered, que quer dizer que algo está blockeando isso. Dá pra resolver isso mudando o SSH para a porta 443, é importante tambem mudar de github.com para "ssh.github.com" assim vc estará se reportando ao webserver ao invés do servidor ssh. segue abaixo os passos para resolver:

Solução:

(Primeiro de tudo tenha certeza que gerou suas keys como explicado no http://help.github.com/win-set-up-git/)

crie o arquivo

> ~/.ssh/config

(o arquivo ssh config fica localizado no diretório do usuário. No Windows provavelmente estará em C:\Users\USERNAME.ssh\config

Cole o seguinte código no arquivo criado:

```
Host github.com
User git
Hostname ssh.github.com
PreferredAuthentications publickey
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Port 443
```

Salve o arquivo.

Execute o ssh:

$ssh -T github.com 
    $Enter passphrase for key '..........

Veja que não precisa fotnecer o username e nem o numero da porta.